Cannot resolve method 'antMatchers' in 'ExpressionInterceptUrlRegistry'
I have the following Spring Security config which I want to migrate to Spring Cloud 3/Spring Security 6:
public class SecurityConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {
  
  @Override
  public void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers(permittedAntMatchers())
        .permitAll();

    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").authenticated();

    final OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint obj =
        new OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint();

    http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(obj);
  }
}

I get multiple errors:
'org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter' is deprecated 

Cannot resolve method 'antMatchers' in 'ExpressionInterceptUrlRegistry'

'org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint' is deprecated 

Do you know how I can migrate properly this code?

AntMatchers are out of date, at least that specific way to use. Please see: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.0-Migration-Guide and https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/wiki/Spring-Security-6.0-Migration-Guide

Can you show me a code example how to migrate the code properly, please?

You should read the documentation, it is made especially to upgrade from earlier versions of Spring Boot, Spring WEB, Spring Security to the current one. These upgrades come with major changes, which are all discovered in the docs. If you just want someone to do that for you, meaning reading the docs and doing the work for you, maybe you're in luck and someone will do it. I'd highly recommend, if you're a serious developer, to give the docs at least a try.

spring-security-oauth2 is end of life since 2022. It is not compatible with Spring Boot 3, Use Spring Security 6 instead.
